# fit or fit_transform if I used StandardScaler on the entire dataset?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I have the a dataframe called features and I scale the data as follows:

```
col_names=features.columns

scaler=StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(features)
standardized_features=scaler.transform(features)
standardized_features.shape
df=pd.DataFrame(data=standardized_features,columns=col_names)
```

Then I split training and test set as follows:

```
df_idx = df[df.Date == '1996-12-01'].index[0]
df_targets=df['Label'].values
df_features=df.drop(['Regime','Date','Label'], axis=1)

df_training_features = df.iloc[:df_idx,:].drop(['Regime','Date','Label'], axis=1)
df_validation_features = df.iloc[df_idx:, :].drop(['Regime','Date','Label'], axis=1)

df_training_targets = df['Label'].values
df_training_targets=df_training_targets[:df_idx]

df_validation_targets = df['Label'].values
df_validation_targets=df_validation_targets[df_idx:]
```

in the end I test different methods:

```
scoring='f1' 
kfold = model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=5) 
models = []

models.append(('LR', LogisticRegression(C=1e10, class_weight = 'balanced')))
models.append(('KNN', KNeighborsClassifier()))
models.append(('GB', GradientBoostingClassifier(random_state = 42)))
models.append(('ABC', AdaBoostClassifier(random_state = 42)))
models.append(('RF', RandomForestClassifier(class_weight = 'balanced')))
models.append(('XGB', xgb.XGBClassifier(objective='binary:logistic', booster='gbtree')))

results = []
names = []
lb = preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()

for name, model in models:
    cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(estimator = model, X = df_training_features, 
                                                 y = lb.fit_transform(df_training_targets), cv=kfold, scoring = scoring)
    
    model.fit(df_training_features, df_training_targets) # train the model

    fpr, tpr, thresholds= metrics.roc_curve(df_training_targets,model.predict_proba(df_training_features)[:,1])
    auc = metrics.roc_auc_score(df_training_targets,model.predict(df_training_features))
    plt.plot(fpr, tpr, label='%s ROC (area = %0.2f)' % (name, auc))
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
    print(msg)
```

My questions are:

- if initially I scaled my data with StandardScaler, is it correct that in the last part I use fit_transform rather than fit as a y argument to model_selection.cross_val_score? Why?
- for the prediction, should I simply use model.predict(df_validation_features)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You must fit you StandScaler with only training data.** Then, with this standardization you transform the training data a and the validation data.

This is done in order to keep the same standarization with all inputs data. Imagine in your training data you have the next values of an attribute: `[0,1,2]`. If you make a simple normalization (it's similar as standarization) you will obtain something like: `[0, 0.5, 1]`.

Now imagine in your validation you have also 3 samples, where one category has the next values `[0, 1, 100]`. If you fit and transform, you will `[0, 0.01, 1]`. This is a disaster, because the model is trained thinking that your 1 is 0.5 scaled. That's why you transform your validation data with training data information.

Comment: thanks a lot Alex, so let me see if I get it. Basically I should invert the first two portion of code, first I split and after I apply the SC as follows: scaler.fit(df_training_features)
standardized_features=scaler.transform(df_training_features) (I substitute features with df_training_features). The third and last code stays the same then in which I use fit_transform, is that right?

Comment: instead for the prediction, is it correct model.predict(scaler.transform(df_validation_features))?

Comment: Yes, with training you can use fit_transform for simplify. With labelizer target, you should do the same, fit from the training data and use only it to transform. The predict seems to be okey, but you should try it.

Comment: thanks!! Just one thing is unclear but it's my fault.."With labelizer target, you should do the same, fit from the training data and use only it to transform". In model_selection.cross_val_score, X=  df_training_features has been fit and transform above as you say, Y was not scaled (because I only applied SC on feature not target) so for simplicity I do y = lb.fit_transform(df_training_targets), is this correct? also when comparing the prediction (second comment) with the validation target (Y_test), I should first scale the validation target as scaler.transform(df_validation_target),right ?

Comment: Your are correct on both questions! :) Happy my comment helps you